# Using registers to specify memory to read with LLDB

Tags: debugging, lldb

I'm trying to teach myself assembly, and am using LLDB to debug. So far, so good, but I'm wondering whether there's a quick way to inspect the memory at an address stored in a register?

Of course, I can do

```
register read rbp
```

(for example), and then use the address via

```
memory read <address> ...
```

but really I'd like to use the register name directly in the arguments to the 'memory' command (possibly with an offset). That seems like a natural thing to want to do, but so far I haven't been able to find anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(lldb) x $eax
0x799be060: f0 e6 1c 01 04 00 00 00 88 23 04 00 98 23 04 00  .........#...#..
0x799be070: a8 23 04 00 b8 23 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .#...#..........
```

To see the memory contents displayed as e.g. 4 floats, use

```
(lldb) x/4f $eax
0x799be060: 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000288183643
0x799be064: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000560519386
0x799be068: 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000380088195
0x799be06c: 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000380110616
```

Comment: Just to expand on Don's answer a bit.  If you look at the help for "x" it will say the arguments are a list of "address-expression"s, and if you run help on "address-expression", it will tell you that is "An expression that resolves to an address".  All convenience variables, including registers, in lldb are prefixed by $.  That's why you have to use the $ in the expression.  But also you can use more general expressions here as you wish.  Just remember that the command line is space-delimited, so you have to use quotes to protect spaces.